# PHP Google App Engine cannot start because php7.dll is missing

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Recently I want to experiment with Google App Engine PHP. Previously I have installed cloud sdk and run smoothly on compute engine.

Here are the problem. I've following instruction carefully from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/quickstart?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=japac-ID-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-b-dr-1003987&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_73116272097-ADGP_Hybrid+%7C+AW+SEM+%7C+BKWS+~+T1+%7C+BMM+%7C+Compute+%7C+M%3A1+%7C+ID+%7C+en+%7C+app+engine+%7C+php-KWID_43700007913023216-kwd-42574416464&userloc_1007701&utm_term=KW_%2Bgoogle%20%2Bapp%20%2Bengine%20%2Bphp&gclid=CjwKCAjwzqPcBRAnEiwAzKRgS5itLTBQ6qkztVKWBcpa0bn2Wuyj80Mf5eYPyNWhyce4N1gXX490xBoCHyMQAvD_BwE&dclid=CM3_t_XQl90CFQzvjwodU1cCjg).

```
git clone -b phase0-helloworld https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-guestbook.git helloworld
cd helloworld
```

I'm stuck on test application hello world app

```
  python dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

When running this code above, there are appears error box

> cannot start because php7.dll is missing

I've check app.yaml and runtime variable using php55.

My machine works on Windows 8.1 X64 and python 2.7. I no have idea whats wrong with my development environment, this is should be easy for basic example hello world. My app engine path as bellow

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\
```

I've register php path that downloaded with Google App Engine, and still doesn't works. Kindly help. thanks

Comment: Your instruction link doesn't work - can you post another link to the instructions you're following?

Comment: Oops sorry my bad. I was wrong copying link. Question edited. Thanks for correction.